# dxdatagrid customized lookup column dropdown with a button at botom

Tags: devextreme

I am working on devextreme dxdatagrid, where I want to show a button in the end of the lookup column dropdown, which will show a popup when clicked.

I searched in the document section but didn't found anything relevant to it.

Please help me to achieve it, ll be thankful if a fiddler example is provided.

Comment: sample fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/wLLastox/19/

Answer (score 4):

You can customize a lookup editor in the grid's [onEditorPreparing](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/?version=16_1#onEditorPreparing) event handler.

Here is a code to add a button at the bottom of lookup editor:

```
onEditorPreparing: function(e){
        if(e.row.rowType === "data" && e.dataField === "formatID") {
        var advancedSearchItem = { 
                template: function(){
                    return $("<div>").dxButton({ 
                text: "Advanced search", 
                onClick: function(args) {
                    alert("click");
                } 
              });       
                }
            };

        e.editorOptions.dataSource = e.lookup.items;
        e.editorOptions.dataSource.push(advancedSearchItem);
      }        
    },
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbkabrq3/